# List sobrescrevendo itens

Tags: c#, lista

Tenho uma List de objeto do tipo Dado, que possui dois atributos: Nome (String) e TransacaoBloqueio (Int)
É a List dadosBloqueioCompartilhado
Porém, a cada execução do método executarSchedule, ela sobrescreve o item sem mesmo eu usar o Add na lista. Alguém pode me dizer onde está o erro?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int contador = 0;
    private Dado dadoAtual = new Dado();
    private string[] linhas;
    private string linhaAtual;
    private int transacaoAtual;
    private char operacaoAtual;
    private List<Dado> dadosBloqueioCompartilhado= new List<Dado>();
    private List<Dado> dadosBloqueioExclusivo = new List<Dado>();
    private List<string> dadosTotal = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void executarSchedule()
    {
        linhaAtual = linhas[contador];
        if (linhaAtual.Equals("00"))
        {
            txtHistorico.Text = "Fim do schedule" + "\r\n";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            transacaoAtual = Convert.ToInt32(linhaAtual.Substring(0, 2));
            operacaoAtual = Convert.ToChar(linhaAtual.Substring(2, 1));
            if (operacaoAtual == 'C')
            {
                txtHistorico.Text += "COMMIT(" + transacaoAtual.ToString() + ")" + "\r\n";
                if(dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Count > 0)
                    foreach(Dado d in dadosBloqueioCompartilhado)
                    {
                        if (d.getTransacaoBloqueio() == transacaoAtual)
                        {
                            dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Remove(d);
                            txtHistorico.Text += "Unlock(" + dadoAtual.getNome() + "," + dadoAtual.getTransacaoBloqueio().ToString() + ")" + "\r\n";
                        }
                        if (dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Count == 0)
                            break;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                dadoAtual.setNome(linhaAtual.Substring(3, 1));
                dadoAtual.setTransacaoBloqueio(transacaoAtual);
                if (!dadosTotal.Contains(dadoAtual.getNome()))
                    dadosTotal.Add(dadoAtual.getNome());
                if(operacaoAtual == 'R')
                {
                    if(dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Count() == 0)
                        dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (Dado d in dadosBloqueioCompartilhado)
                        {
                            if (!(d.getNome() == dadoAtual.getNome() && d.getTransacaoBloqueio() == dadoAtual.getTransacaoBloqueio()))
                                dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
                        }
                    }
                    txtHistorico.Text += "Lock-S(" + dadoAtual.getNome() + "," + dadoAtual.getTransacaoBloqueio().ToString() + ")" + "\r\n";
                    txtHistorico.Text += "Read(" + dadoAtual.getNome() + ")" + "\r\n";
                }
                else if(operacaoAtual == 'W')
                {

                }
            }             

        }
        contador++;
    }
```

Comment: De que item está falando? Este código é ruim porque mistura lógica de tela com a lógica de negócio. Tem um `if` completamente desnecessário e outro usado para corrigir gambiarra errada. Então dá para imaginar que muita coisa aí pode estar errada e pode ser em pontos nem mostrados. Uma erro bastante óbvio é varrer uma coleção com `foreach` e remover itens desta coleção, isto bagunça a enumeração completamente. E tem `Add()`, que causa problema na enumeração também.Várias coisas neste código não parecem fazer o menor sentido.

Comment: @bigown É a lista dadosBloqueioCompartilhado. Toda vez que adiciono um item ela, ela remove o anterior. Está sobrescrevendo ao invés de incrementar. Sobre o foreach, como fazer então para procurar um item na lista e removê-lo de outra forma?